Appearance of text in notebook
I'm running Mathematica 13 on Linux, both at home and at work.
I brought a notebook I was working on at home to work, but when I opened it the commands were completely out of place - characters seem to be on the wrong positions on screen. Apart from that, everything seems to be working fine - but working on the code is challenging since I can't really see where the cursor actually is.
Both installations are running on Debian Trixie, both up to date, and with effectively the same packages installed.
At home, everything looks fine (as they should). However, when I opened this notebook at work, I had the situation illustrated in the pictures below. I took the care of timing the screenshot so the cursor is active in both.

In the image above, I have the notebook as it was opened in Mathematica. Notice how the letter spacing looks strange - lines seem stretched far beyond where they should end.

In the image above, I have the very same notebook, after I typed "x" in the keyboard. Notice that, despite the cursor seemingly being between "Evaluate" and "@Table", the "x" appeared between letters "t" and "e".
Any suggestions as to how I could handle this issue?

I think it's better to directly contact WRI?
